# How to understand the explain plan in Hive?

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I have a query which I need to tune. with assistance of many good folks of Stack Overflow, I did few suggested changes and it did work; but really want to understand the explain plan in Hive, and try to tune the query myself.

Query -

```
CREATE TABLE admin.FctPrfitAmt_rpt AS
SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt t2 
WHERE t2.scenario_id NOT exists (SELECT 1 from  admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr t3 where t2.scenario_id = t3.scenario_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr
```

Explain plan:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-10 is a root stage
  Stage-15 depends on stages: Stage-1, Stage-10, Stage-16 , consists of Stage-18, Stage-2
  Stage-18 has a backup stage: Stage-2
  Stage-14 depends on stages: Stage-18
  Stage-3 depends on stages: Stage-2, Stage-14
  Stage-9 depends on stages: Stage-3 , consists of Stage-6, Stage-5, Stage-7
  Stage-6
  Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-6, Stage-5, Stage-8
  Stage-20 depends on stages: Stage-0
  Stage-4 depends on stages: Stage-20
  Stage-5
  Stage-7
  Stage-8 depends on stages: Stage-7
  Stage-2
  Stage-11 is a root stage
  Stage-12 depends on stages: Stage-11
  Stage-17 depends on stages: Stage-12 , consists of Stage-19, Stage-1
  Stage-19 has a backup stage: Stage-1
  Stage-16 depends on stages: Stage-19
  Stage-1

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-10
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t3
            Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: scenario_id (type: bigint)
              outputColumnNames: scenario_id
              Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Group By Operator
                keys: scenario_id (type: bigint)
                mode: hash
                outputColumnNames: _col0
                Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Reduce Output Operator
                  key expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
                  sort order: +
                  Map-reduce partition columns: _col0 (type: bigint)
                  Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          keys: KEY._col0 (type: bigint)
          mode: mergepartial
          outputColumnNames: _col0
          Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          File Output Operator
            compressed: false
            table:
                input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe

  Stage: Stage-15
    Conditional Operator

  Stage: Stage-18
    Map Reduce Local Work
      Alias -> Map Local Tables:
        reconcile-subquery1:t1-subquery1:$INTNAME1 
          Fetch Operator
            limit: -1
      Alias -> Map Local Operator Tree:
        reconcile-subquery1:t1-subquery1:$INTNAME1 
          TableScan
            HashTable Sink Operator
              keys:
                0 _col0 (type: bigint)
                1 _col0 (type: bigint)

  Stage: Stage-14
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            Map Join Operator
              condition map:
                   Left Outer Join0 to 1
              keys:
                0 _col0 (type: bigint)
                1 _col0 (type: bigint)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7, _col11
              Statistics: Num rows: 715121683 Data size: 39113453068 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Filter Operator
                predicate: _col11 is null (type: boolean)
                Statistics: Num rows: 357560841 Data size: 19556726506 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Select Operator
                  expressions: _col0 (type: bigint), _col1 (type: bigint), _col2 (type: bigint), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: double), _col5 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col6 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col7 (type: decimal(25,13))
                  outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
                  Statistics: Num rows: 357560841 Data size: 19556726506 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  File Output Operator
                    compressed: false
                    table:
                        input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                        output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                        serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe
      Local Work:
        Map Reduce Local Work

  Stage: Stage-3
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            Union
              Statistics: Num rows: 396637128 Data size: 21840112219 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              File Output Operator
                compressed: false
                Statistics: Num rows: 396637128 Data size: 21840112219 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                table:
                    input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                    output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                    serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                    name: admin.FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark
          TableScan
            alias: FctPrfitAmt_incr
            Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: scenario_id (type: bigint), facility_id (type: bigint), process_id (type: bigint), mp_surrogate_id (type: int), units (type: double), raw_amount (type: decimal(25,13)), allocation_percent (type: decimal(25,13)), capacity_allocation_percent (type: decimal(25,13))
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
              Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Union
                Statistics: Num rows: 396637128 Data size: 21840112219 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                File Output Operator
                  compressed: false
                  Statistics: Num rows: 396637128 Data size: 21840112219 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  table:
                      input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                      output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                      serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                      name: admin.FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark

  Stage: Stage-9
    Conditional Operator

  Stage: Stage-6
    Move Operator
      files:
          hdfs directory: true
          destination: hdfs://nameservice1/admin/.hive-staging_hive_2017-04-24_04-17-27_639_6500987676644679103-777/-ext-10001

  Stage: Stage-0
    Move Operator
      files:
          hdfs directory: true
          destination: hdfs://nameservice1/admin/FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark

  Stage: Stage-20
      Create Table Operator:
        Create Table
          columns: scenario_id bigint, facility_id bigint, process_id bigint, mp_surrogate_id int, units double, raw_amount decimal(25,13), allocation_percent decimal(25,13), capacity_allocation_percent decimal(25,13)
          input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
          output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
          serde name: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
          name: admin.FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark

  Stage: Stage-4
    Stats-Aggr Operator

  Stage: Stage-5
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            File Output Operator
              compressed: false
              table:
                  input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                  output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                  serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                  name: admin.FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark

  Stage: Stage-7
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            File Output Operator
              compressed: false
              table:
                  input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                  output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                  serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
                  name: admin.FctPrfitAmt_reporting_k_benchmark

  Stage: Stage-8
    Move Operator
      files:
          hdfs directory: true
          destination: hdfs://nameservice1/admin/.hive-staging_hive_2017-04-24_04-17-27_639_6500987676644679103-777/-ext-10001

  Stage: Stage-2
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            Reduce Output Operator
              key expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
              sort order: +
              Map-reduce partition columns: _col0 (type: bigint)
              Statistics: Num rows: 650110607 Data size: 35557683837 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              value expressions: _col1 (type: bigint), _col2 (type: bigint), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: double), _col5 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col6 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col7 (type: decimal(25,13))
          TableScan
            Reduce Output Operator
              key expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
              sort order: +
              Map-reduce partition columns: _col0 (type: bigint)
              Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Join Operator
          condition map:
               Left Outer Join0 to 1
          keys:
            0 _col0 (type: bigint)
            1 _col0 (type: bigint)
          outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7, _col11
          Statistics: Num rows: 715121683 Data size: 39113453068 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Filter Operator
            predicate: _col11 is null (type: boolean)
            Statistics: Num rows: 357560841 Data size: 19556726506 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: _col0 (type: bigint), _col1 (type: bigint), _col2 (type: bigint), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: double), _col5 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col6 (type: decimal(25,13)), _col7 (type: decimal(25,13))
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
              Statistics: Num rows: 357560841 Data size: 19556726506 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              File Output Operator
                compressed: false
                table:
                    input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                    output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                    serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe

  Stage: Stage-11
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t3
            filterExpr: scenario_id is null (type: boolean)
            Statistics: Num rows: 39076287 Data size: 2283385713 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Filter Operator
              predicate: scenario_id is null (type: boolean)
              Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Select Operator
                expressions: null (type: bigint)
                outputColumnNames: scenario_id
                Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                Group By Operator
                  keys: scenario_id (type: bigint)
                  mode: hash
                  outputColumnNames: _col0
                  Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                  Reduce Output Operator
                    key expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
                    sort order: +
                    Map-reduce partition columns: _col0 (type: bigint)
                    Statistics: Num rows: 19538143 Data size: 1141692827 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          keys: KEY._col0 (type: bigint)
          mode: mergepartial
          outputColumnNames: _col0
          Statistics: Num rows: 9769071 Data size: 570846384 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Select Operator
            Statistics: Num rows: 9769071 Data size: 570846384 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Group By Operator
              aggregations: count()
              mode: hash
              outputColumnNames: _col0
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              File Output Operator
                compressed: false
                table:
                    input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                    output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                    serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe

  Stage: Stage-12
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            Reduce Output Operator
              sort order: 
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              value expressions: _col0 (type: bigint)
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Group By Operator
          aggregations: count(VALUE._col0)
          mode: mergepartial
          outputColumnNames: _col0
          Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Filter Operator
            predicate: (_col0 = 0) (type: boolean)
            Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Select Operator
              expressions: 0 (type: bigint)
              outputColumnNames: _col0
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              Group By Operator
                keys: _col0 (type: bigint)
                mode: hash
                outputColumnNames: _col0
                Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
                File Output Operator
                  compressed: false
                  table:
                      input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                      output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                      serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe

  Stage: Stage-17
    Conditional Operator

  Stage: Stage-19
    Map Reduce Local Work
      Alias -> Map Local Tables:
        reconcile-subquery1:t1-subquery1:$INTNAME 
          Fetch Operator
            limit: -1
      Alias -> Map Local Operator Tree:
        reconcile-subquery1:t1-subquery1:$INTNAME 
          TableScan
            HashTable Sink Operator
              keys:
0
1

  Stage: Stage-16
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t2
            Statistics: Num rows: 591009630 Data size: 32325166424 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Map Join Operator
              condition map:
                   Left Semi Join 0 to 1
              keys:
0
1
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
              Statistics: Num rows: 650110607 Data size: 35557683837 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              File Output Operator
                compressed: false
                table:
                    input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                    output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                    serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe
      Local Work:
        Map Reduce Local Work

  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: t2
            Statistics: Num rows: 591009630 Data size: 32325166424 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Reduce Output Operator
              sort order: 
              Statistics: Num rows: 591009630 Data size: 32325166424 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
              value expressions: scenario_id (type: bigint), facility_id (type: bigint), process_id (type: bigint), mp_surrogate_id (type: int), units (type: double), raw_amount (type: decimal(25,13)), allocation_percent (type: decimal(25,13)), capacity_allocation_percent (type: decimal(25,13))
          TableScan
            Reduce Output Operator
              sort order: 
              Statistics: Num rows: 1 Data size: 8 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
      Reduce Operator Tree:
        Join Operator
          condition map:
               Left Semi Join 0 to 1
          keys:
0
1
          outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
          Statistics: Num rows: 650110607 Data size: 35557683837 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          File Output Operator
            compressed: false
            table:
                input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat
                output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
                serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinarySerDe
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a incremental operation.

we use full join, just generate one mapreduce job .

```
CREATE TABLE admin.FctPrfitAmt_rpt AS
SELECT 
   case when t3.scenario_id is null then t2.scenario_id else t3.scenario_id as scenario_id ,
   case when t3.scenario_id is null then t2.COL1 else t3.COL1 as COL1 ,
   case when t3.scenario_id is null then t2.COL2 else t3.COL2 as COL2 ,
   case when t3.scenario_id is null then t2.COL3 else t3.COL3 as COL3 ,
   ........
FROM admin.FctPrfitAmt t2 
full join  admin.FctPrfitAmt_incr t3 on t2.scenario_id  = t3.scenario_id
```

Comment: This solution is not relevant since `scenario_id` is not unique on both tables